# Setting tag property for librato metrics with librato-metrics node package

Tags: node.js, librato

I am using `node-metrics` package for posting librato metrics and not able to figure out how to add tags to the metrics. I tried below code but it does not work. It posts the metrics fine but I do not see any tags attached to the metrics as shown here: https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/faq/glossary/whats_a_tag/

code:

```
client.post("/metrics", {
                gauges: [
                    {name: "NameOfMetrics", value: 55, tag: "tag1"}
                ],
            }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("ERROR: in publishing metrics - " + err.message);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

found out that my account does not support tags but it supports source attribute to filter metrics: https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/faq/account_questions/tags_or_sources/